# Largest divisible subset in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given an array the task is to find the largest divisible subset in array. A subset is called divisible if for every pair (x, y) in subset, either x divides y or y divides x.

Example

Input  : arr[] = {1, 16, 7, 8, 4}
Output : 16 8 4 1
In the output subset, for every pair,
either the first element divides second
or second divides first.

Input  : arr[] = {2, 4, 3, 8}
Output : 8 4 2

Here is what I have come up with. The time complexity is O(n^2). can it be improved ?

```
public static int[] largestDivisibleSubset2(int[] a){

    Arrays.sort(a);
    int index=0;
    int maxDivCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        int currentDivCount=0;
        for (int j=i;j<a.length;j++ ) {
            if(a[j]%a[i]==0){
                currentDivCount++;
            }
        }
        if(currentDivCount>maxDivCount){
            index = i;
            maxDivCount = currentDivCount;
        }
        currentDivCount = 0;
    }
    int[] res = new int[maxDivCount];
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(a[i]%a[index]==0){
            res[k++] = a[i];            
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Note : you have to check if your element is not 0 else you will get `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`

Comment: How large can the numbers be? It's possible to something like `O(N * d + N * sqrt(MAX_VAL))`, where `d` is the maximum number of divisors for all elements of the input array.

Comment: Could you give more information about why you are worried about time complexity (over code simplicity)? Presumably you are considering massive numbers of items in the set? If so, do you want answers that include parellising the task?

Comment: @sprinter - preparing for interviews mate :)

Comment: Your mileage may vary but, personally, I have never asked someone to optimise performance of code by inspection while I'm interviewing them for a job. I have always asked them to solve a problem elegantly or find errors or improve readability / testability / maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

On modern multi-core machines (and the much improved facilities for use of them in Java 8) it is often easier to look for ways to use all cores before optimising sequential processing times. This is especially true if reducing time complexity will also reduce readability or maintainability.

For example, here's a solution to your problem that uses parallel streams in Java 8 while deciding whether to add a value to a subset. On my own ancient machine it can find the largest divisible subset of 50,000 random integers in 14 secs (22 seconds if I remove the `parallel` method). There are clearly optimisations possible but, unless there's a specific reason, choose clarity first. Especially in interviews :-)

```
public int[] getSubSet(int... set) {
    int[] largest = new int[0];
    for (int value : set) {
        int[] subset = Arrays.stream(set).parallel()
                .filter(n -> n % value == 0 || value % n == 0).toArray();
        if (subset.length > largest.length)
            largest = subset;
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Comment: You got my up vote. Thanks a lot for the helpful tip.

Comment: Theoretically, the complexity is still O(n^2) right?